# Is my electrical panel big enough for my hot tub?

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel, hot-tub

I just bought a hot tub that requires a 240 volt, 50 amp dedicated circuit. My electrical panel has a rating of 100 Amps. Max. All the breaker slots are full but I am wondering if I could consolidate and install a 50 Amp Double-Pole and (2) 15 Amp Single-Pole Type QT Triplex Circuit Breaker to make room for my hot tub, or if I will need to upgrade the whole panel. (see pictures)[image]

Comment: How big is your house in square feet?

Comment: It is 1750 squarefeet.

Comment: Highly recommended that you get a professional opinion.  You're likely looking at adding a new subpanel just to control the tub.  It would be wired just after the master 100 Amp breaker.  But you will want advice for cable size, etc.  This is a lot like installing a full-house A/C unit.  You can do it, but it must be done right.

Comment: To be sure, I'd do a load calculation on the home, including the new hot tub load.  This will tell you if 100 amp service is enough for all the loads (including the hot tub) in the home, or if you'll need to upgrade the service.

Comment: One more question: what are the nameplate wattage ratings on your A/C and range/oven?

Comment: BTW -- can you get us a photo of the panel's information label?